# Initialise JQuery Date Picker

Tags: jquery, typescript

I have the following code

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });

  var searchStartDate = moment((<any>$('#searchStart')).datepicker('getDate'));
  var searchEndDate = moment((<any>$('#searchEnd')).datepicker('getDate'));
```

I am getting an error on datepicker on the first line:

> The property "datepicker" does not exist on value of type "JQueryStatic"

Can someone point me in the right direction to fix it please?

Comment: do you have included the jquery ui library?

Comment: Did you put that code in document ready wrapper? $(function(){ [your code here] });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have the jQuery declaration file but not the *jQuery UI* declaration file.  It's available here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jqueryui

**Edit**: Modern TypeScript development is installing packages through npm rather than downloading files manually.  Install the declaration file with `npm install --save @types/jqueryui`.

Comment: Fixed the link and updated how declaration dependencies should be added to a project.